# What does = :user_receiver do in this sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 $sqlinfo = "SELECT * FROM user_notifications WHERE
             user_receiver       = :user_receiver AND
             user_status         = :user_status";
```

What do = :user_receiver  and = :user_status, do in the sql query, and why do we need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are parameters used to safeguard the data and, for example, to protect the query from [SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). These are not part of SQL but are placeholders used by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or another prepared statement/query builder.

So when this query is actually executed, these are going to be replaced with some input provided at the time of execution.

Comment: And "why" we use bind placeholders... its the primary defense against SQL Injection vulnerabilities.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @spencer7593 yea this is in the first sentence